# How to read file which has no delimiter in SAS?

Tags: sas

**Problem Statement:**

I am trying to read the following file in SAS (Below is the content of  file that I am trying to read)

```
MicrosoftBillGates1976
AppleSteaveJob1975
GoogleLarryPage2004
FacebookMarkZukerberg2004
TwitterBizStone2006
```

**I have tried following code:**

```
DATA CN;
INFILE 'W:\NMIMS\Sem 1\SAS\Datasets\CN.txt';
length Founder $10;
INPUT Name $1-9 Founder$10-23 Founded $24-29 ;
RUN;

PROC PRINT DATA = CN;
RUN;
```

But no luck so far.
Can somebody help me here? And give some explanation as well.

Comment: Is it actually fixed width or are those arbitrary numbers? The characters 1-9 for record 2 are `AppleStev`.

Comment: There is no space or use of any delimiter in-between values.

Comment: Then how do you tell your program that the first value is `Microsoft` and the second is `Apple`?

Comment: I am trying to use Column Input method. If I am doing any mistake then please share the proper solution with an explanation that would help me.

Comment: Not possible unless you have a very limited and consistent set of data that you can separate by the exact upper case value of the first character of each word. Which in my experience is not going to happen for a number of reasons (names are never explicitly 1 or 2 words long etc.)

Comment: Programs require rules, what are the rules? Even if it's camelCase there has to be some rules that can go. Company names could be AppleSteave and the person name could be Jobs, how do you know which goes with name and which goes with company name? Otherwise this is a best guess exercise in futility. Column input requires that data always start at specific column. Where did you get this data from? I'm going to assume there's a better source.

Answer (score 2):

You could use regex matching to detect the start of propercased words:

```
data want;
input @;
array c[3] $16. Company Firstname Lastname;
retain regex;
if _n_ = 1 then regex = prxparse('/[A-Z][a-z]+/');
start = 1;
stop = length(_infile_);
do i = 1 to 3;
  call prxnext(regex,start, stop, _infile_, position,length);
  c[i] = substr(_infile_,position,length);
end;
Year = input(substr(_infile_,position + length),8.);
input;
keep Company Firstname Lastname Year;
cards;
MicrosoftBillGates1976
AppleSteaveJob1975
GoogleLarryPage2004
FacebookMarkZukerberg2004
TwitterBizStone2006
;
run;
```

If your data source is not consistently propercased then it would probably be easier to pay people to manually transcribe it into separate fields.

Comment: What if you have a company called VirginGalactic with an owner called SirRichardBranson?

Comment: @JacobH - an excellent illustration of the limitations of this approach. Unfortunately I suspect this is the best one can do with such an awful data format.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately you'll need to create a macro that parses out each line using [ANYDIGIT()](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002194193.htm) and [ANYUPPER()](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002194376.htm).

A similar question was asked and answered here: https://communities.sas.com/t5/Base-SAS-Programming/Split-the-string-into-two-parts/td-p/133091

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Presume: Field differentiation is by CamelCase, wherein the company is the first hump, the name the remaining alpha characters, followed by year.

Input the raw line and process it.

- Way 1 is to use `indexc` to isolate the start of important humps.
- Way 2 is to use a Perl regular expression pattern to identifying the parts.
- Way *N* is to use ...

Example

```
data want;
  input;
  * presume field differentiation is only know via camel-case;
  index1 = indexc(_infile_, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ');
  index2 = indexc(substr(_infile_,index1+1), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ') + 1;
  index3 = indexc(substr(_infile_,index2+1), '1234567890') + index2;

  length company person $50 year 8;

  company = substr(_infile_,index1,index2-index1);
  person  = substr(_infile_,index2,index3-index2);
  year = input (substr(_infile_, index3), 4.);

  * or regex way;
  if _n_ = 1 then do;
    rx = prxparse ('/^([A-Z][^A-Z]*)([^0-9]*)(\d{4})\s*$/');
    retain rx;
  end;

  if prxmatch (rx, _infile_) then do;
    length company2 person2 $50 year2 8;
    company2 = prxposn(rx,1,_infile_);
    person2  = prxposn(rx,2,_infile_);
    year2 = input (prxposn(rx,3,_infile_), 4.);
  end;
datalines;
MicrosoftBillGates1976
AppleSteaveJob1975
GoogleLarryPage2004
FacebookMarkZukerberg2004
TwitterBizStone2006
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's always best practice to use a standardized delimited files for data processing.

Solution 1: Datalines

```
data output1; 
   input line $40.; 
   p = anyupper(line,2);
   d=anydigit(line);
   f=anyupper(substrn(line,p,d-p),2);
   Company = substrn(line,1,p-1);
   name=substrn(line,p,d-p);
   Forename = substrn(substrn(line,p,d-p),1,f-1);
   Surname =substrn(substrn(line,p,d-p),f);
   Year=substrn(line,d);
   drop line p d f name ;
   put _all_; 
   cards; 
   MicrosoftBillGates1976
   AppleSteaveJob1975
   GoogleLarryPage2004
   FacebookMarkZukerberg2004
   TwitterBizStone2006
   ;;;;
   run;
```

Solution 2: External file

```
/*Read External File*/
DATA WORK.cn;
    LENGTH
        F1               $ 25 ;
    FORMAT
        F1               $CHAR25. ;
    INFORMAT
        F1               $CHAR25. ;
    INFILE 'E:\saswork\cn.txt' /* Change this to your file path*/
        LRECL=25
        ENCODING="WLATIN1"
        TERMSTR=CRLF
        DLM='7F'x  /*I am using comma delimiter "," */
        MISSOVER
        DSD ;
    INPUT
        F1               : $CHAR25. ;
RUN;
/*Parse Columns and save data*/
data output2; 
set work.cn;
   p = anyupper(f1,2);
   d=anydigit(f1);
   f=anyupper(substrn(f1,p,d-p),2);
   Company = substrn(f1,1,p-1);
   name=substrn(f1,p,d-p);
   Forename = substrn(substrn(f1,p,d-p),1,f-1);
   Surname =substrn(substrn(f1,p,d-p),f);
   Year=substrn(f1,d);
   drop f1  p d f name ;
   put _all_; 
   run;
```

Output:

```
Company=Microsoft name=BillGates Forename=Bill Surname=Gates Year=1976 
Company=Apple name=SteaveJob Forename=Steave Surname=Job Year=1975 
Company=Google name=LarryPage Forename=Larry Surname=Page Year=2004 
Company=Facebook name=MarkZukerberg Forename=Mark Surname=Zukerberg Year=2004 
Company=Twitter name=BizStone Forename=Biz Surname=Stone Year=2006
```